# How can a human understand the Xamarin.iOS Storyboard designer's ambiguous layout constraints section?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, autolayout, storyboard

Xamarin.iOS Autolayout uses the following terms in the constraints section:

- Top Space to...
- Bottom Space to...
- Leading Space to...
- Trailing Space to...

This would be clear if the source object and the target object had opposing descriptions (X is the top to Y's bottom), but this isn't the case.

In fact, what is happening, X is the top to Y's top.  This confuses manual inspection of either X or Y, since they are both described as "top".

**Detailed example**

When I create a layout constraint between a Label and a Button, each one has a "leading space to X" where X is the other object.

Example, Here both the button and the label have a leading space "to each other".  What is the value of the words "leading space".  Every one of the key words seems to have a context that I haven't yet parsed.

**Button has a "leading space" of 12 to switch**

[image]

**Switch has a 12 "leading space" to button**
[image]

**Question**

- How can "Leading space" be the correct term for space that is obviously on the left of one element, and on the right of the other?
- How can I look at constraints and figure out the relative dependency, or even begin to manually parse the layout system ... when every element "leads" the other?
- Where do I begin to gain perspective on how to debug a funky layout?

Comment: Looks like this is a Xamarin issue... iOS seems to swap the leading/trailing

Comment: it is relative to the object you observe not to the entire scene. For example: if you look at the button - the 12 leading space to switch means "left edge" of the button. Trailing means "right egde". Btw, the second image does not match the first. So your switch will have trailing to button = button's leading to switch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meanings of “Leading” and “Trailing” depend on the device's locale.

If the locale is a left-to-right (LTR) locale (like English), then “Leading” means “Left” and “Trailing” means “Right”.

If the locale is a right-to-left (RTL) locale (like Hebrew or Arabic), then “Leading” means “Right” and “Trailing” means “Left”.

If you want to understand auto layout, it would be a very good idea to watch some of the WWDC videos about it. Here's a list of most of them:

- [WWDC 2012 Introduction to Auto Layout for iOS and OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/202/)
- [WWDC 2012 Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/228/)
- [WWDC 2012 Auto Layout by Example](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/232/)
- [WWDC 2013 Taking Control of Auto Layout in Xcode 5](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/406/)
- [WWDC 2015 Mysteries of Auto Layout, Part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/218/)
- [WWDC 2015 Mysteries of Auto Layout, Part 2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/219/)
- [WWDC 2016 What's New in Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/236/)
- [WWDC 2017 Auto Layout Techniques in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/412/)

You can also find auto layout tutorials on the web in either written or video form.

Comment: This is AWESOME! ... but it looks like this is a bug that no one seems to have brought up w.r.t. the Xamarin iOS designer. Xcode seems fine, which also clarified my temporary insanity.